# PHP reading csv and using fputcsv: how can I skip the whole row with an if condition

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fputcsv

I am trying to recreate a csv file based on another csv source file. I am trying to skip the whole row when that row has a specific word "WORDO". For now I'm only able to replace the data which has "WORDO" by some empty string (""). However I would like to skip the whole row when a match is found, . For now the $keepColumns array still keeps data[1] ( empty, or not) I would like to skip the whole row when "WORDO" is inside $data[1]

```
<?php

$finalArray = array();
$newFinalData = "new_csv.csv";

if (($finalData = fopen("mycsv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {

    $newfile = fopen($newFinalData, 'w');

    while (($data = fgetcsv($finalData, 999999, ",",'"')) !== FALSE)
        {

        //If the 1st column has WORDO as text, ideally skip the whole row
        if( substr( $data[1], 0, 5 ) === "WORDO" ) {
            $data[1] = "";
        }

        $keepColumns = array(

            $data[0],
            $data[1],
            $data[2],
            $data[5]

        );

        fputcsv($newfile, $keepColumns, ";",'"');
        }
    fclose($finalData);
    fclose($newfile);
    }


?>
```

Comment: Use the word `continue;`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the keyword `continue` to literally skip to the next iteration:

```
        if( substr( $data[1], 0, 5 ) === "WORDO" ) {
            $data[1] = "";
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: Incidentally, `$data[1] = "";` becomes irrelevant if you're just going to continue.

Comment: And I would probably use `if(strpos($data[1], "WORDO") === 0)`

Comment: He might use it later, you never know.